# Combine duplicate rows into one record in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a date frame that has many rows and looks approximately like this:

```
A        B
Lukas    Switzerland
Lukas    Italy
Simon    Germany
Simon    Portugal
Simon    Korea
```

I would like the data to look like this

```
A        B
Lukas    Switzerland, Italy
Simon    Germany, Portugal, Korea
```

How can I do this in excel?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Office 365

- I created a table of the data and Named it `countryTbl` *(but you could use regular references if you prefer)*

```
D2: =UNIQUE(countryTbl[Name])
E2: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(countryTbl[Country],countryTbl[Name]=D2))
```

`D2` will SPILL the results automatically.
`E2` will need to be filled down

[image]

If you don't have Office 365, you can also do this in Power Query.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change Table Name in next line to reflect the actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="countryTbl"]}[Content],

//Set the data types.
//If you have different column names than "Name" and "Country" , you may need to edit this line
//   as well as the next code line
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Country", type text}}),

//Group by "Name"
// then use List.Accumulate to aggregate the text in each Group with a ", " separator
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {
        {"Countries", each List.Accumulate([Country],"",
                (state, current)=> if state = "" then current else state & ", " & current),
                 Text.Type                
                }       
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the formulas Ron has suggested you could do this using Power Query.

1 Select the data.

2 Go to Data>Get & Transform Data>From Sheet.

3 In Power Query go to View>Advanced Editor and replace any code there with this.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Countries" = Table.Group(Source, {"Column1"}, {{"Column2 Values", each Text.Combine([Column2],","), type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Countries,{{"Column1", "Name"}, {"Column2 Values", "Countries"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

4 To return the data to Excel go to File>Close & Load.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Ron has suggested, if your intention is not to summarize entries, but to use it as a way to search for a key (name) and show all possible matches for it, you can define (since Office 365 version):

Column D with Key to search

Column E in this example E2:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER($B$2:$B$6;D2=$A$2:$A$6))`

[image: Excel Screen]